# How to add Android calendar events that do not become tentative meetings in exchange?

Tags: android

I have a small application where one of the features include having a current status for the user. This is shown to other users using our backend and in some cases there should also be the option to have the status sync with the user's calendar.

I use the ICS calendar API:s to perform this sync and it works well with Google calendar. If the user chooses to sync with an exchange account however the status items show up as meeting requests with status tentative.

Since I have limited experience with calendars my question is what fields that should go with the calendar event to make it appear as a regular event in exchange as well as Google calendar. I insert events directly, without using intents because the aim is for this to be seamless for the user. The current code looks like this (status is my status data model).

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, status.StartTimeLocal.getTime());
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, status.StopTimeLocal.getTime());
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, status.DisplayName);
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, status.Text);
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.AVAILABILITY, CalendarContract.Events.AVAILABILITY_BUSY);
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.STATUS, CalendarContract.Events.STATUS_CONFIRMED);
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.GUESTS_CAN_INVITE_OTHERS, false);
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ATTENDEE_DATA, false);
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, mCalendarId);
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, "Europe/Stockholm");
Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

When I try adding a new item manually in the phone calendar it syncs correctly with exchange so it seems possible. But from my app I have a hard time getting it to work.

Answer (score 2):

Specifying the `Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT` in your ContentValues should do the trick.

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
...
values.put(Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT, ACCOUNT_NAME);
```

Before inserting, your CONTENT_URI needs to include the ACCOUNT_NAME, and ACCOUNT_TYPE

```
Uri contentUri CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI
        .buildUpon()
        .appendQueryParameter(Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, ACCOUNT_NAME)
        .appendQueryParameter(Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, "com.google")
        .build();
```

Now insert:

```
Uri uri = cr.insert(contentUri, values);
```

Comment: I have issues implementing this solution since I am not doing this from a sync adapter but from a regular application. If I try this from my application I get an error that only sync adapters are allowed to write to owner account.Also this seems to refer to entire calendars (CalendarContract.Calendar) and not events (CalendarContract.Events).

Comment: @BMB did you manage to insert an event with status set to confirmed from your app?

Comment: No, I have not managed to get this to work with exchange with the events showing up as something other than tentative meetings. Will update here if I find a solution.